# How to make an ellipse follow a curve on a canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having an issue trying to get an ellipse to properly follow a path on my canvas. I supposed the problem stems from the fact that my mini syntax defines movement between x and y values but am targeting only one of those values in my target property (e.g. (`Canvas.Top` or `Canvas.Left`). I can not seem to find any attached "Position" property on the canvas that would take in a Position type which would work with my path. What would be the proper way to get this path to work?

```
<Canvas Name="WaitingCanvas">
            <Ellipse Name="WaitingEllipse"
                     Canvas.Top="100"
                     Canvas.Left="50"
                     Height="20"
                     Width="20"
                     Fill="White">
                <Ellipse.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingPath
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="WaitingEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"

                                    Source="X" 
                                    Duration="0:0:5">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 50,100 C 100,50 150,100 200, 100"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>


                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Ellipse.Triggers>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't animate both `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` at the same time, but you can [use two separate animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath.aspx).  Make the `PathGeometry` a resources so it can be shared:

```
<Canvas Name="WaitingCanvas">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Name="AnimationPath" Figures="M 50,100 C 100,50 150,100 200, 100"/>
    </Canvas.Resources>
        <Ellipse Name="WaitingEllipse"
                 Canvas.Top="100"
                 Canvas.Left="50"
                 Height="20"
                 Width="20"
                 Fill="White">
            <Ellipse.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath
                                Storyboard.TargetName="WaitingEllipse"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                PathGeometry="{StaticResource AnimationPath}"
                                Source="X" 
                                Duration="0:0:5" />
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath
                                Storyboard.TargetName="WaitingEllipse"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                PathGeometry="{StaticResource AnimationPath}"
                                Source="Y" 
                                Duration="0:0:5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Ellipse.Triggers>
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: I thought about this but I don't seem to understand the concept of the path in this sense. If the path defines a curve with 3 sets of x and y values and I am defining only one coordinate of the canvas with both x and y values won't it not work? In my case I get an ellipse that travels on a diagonal line and not a curve.

Comment: @Adrian right, but that's why you use 2 animations -- one binds Canvas.Left to the x component, the other Canvas.Top to the y.

Comment: Okay so I'm guessing binding to Canvas.Left will ignore all the y values in my path? Seems kinda clunky on microsofts parts boo. I'll give it a shot again.

Comment: @Adrian only because you specify `Source="X"` -- that says, use the x-coordinate of the path for the animation

Comment: Ahh so that's what that does. Haha.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of simultaneously animating `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` you may perhaps also animate the  `Matrix` property of a `MatrixTransform` that is assigned to the `RenderTransform` property of the Ellipse. The `Matrix` would be animated by a `MatrixAnimationUsingPath`.

```
<Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Fill="White">
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <MatrixTransform x:Name="transform" Matrix="1,0,0,1,50,100"/>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <MatrixAnimationUsingPath
                        Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix"
                        Duration="0:0:5">
                        <MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 50,100 C 100,50 150,100 200,100"/>
                        </MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                    </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

---

Using a `MatrixAnimationUsingPath` would even allow to rotate the animated element along the tangent of the animation path, by setting `DoesRotateWithTangent="True"`. That would of course only be visible if the animated element wouldn't be a circle.

Comment: This is awesome -- wish they had this in Silverlight.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Can you please explain what the "M" and "C" stands for in the PathGeometry tag? If possible can you share a link for its detailed explanation.

Comment: @Tejus Online documentation on MSDN: [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx).

Comment: Thank you @Clemens. The link to Path Markup Syntax seems to be broken now. Here is the new link to those who wish to know more on this topic. [Path Markup Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041(v=vs.95).aspx)