# Storyboard EllipseGeometry animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, storyboard, styles

all. I have started a simple WPF application and would like a button to follow an elliptical path when it is made visible(for now I just want it to occur when I click...for testing purposes). It should simply move along the path then come to rest at the final point. I am having trouble getting the storyboard to work in a style. It won't reference the path that I have already defined. How do I resolve this? Eventually, each button will need to have it's own final resting point, so I will need to pass in an extra animation at a later date. The code is in XAML(posted below).

```
<Window x:Class="EllipseFollowsPath.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EllipseFollowsPath"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="768" Width="1366">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="path">
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="921,384" IsClosed="False">
                    <ArcSegment Point="445,384" Size="60 60" 
                    SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"/>
                </PathFigure>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="445,384" IsClosed="False">
                    <ArcSegment Point="921,384" Size="60 60" 
                    SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
        <Storyboard x:Key="sb" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <MatrixAnimationUsingPath
                    Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix"
                    PathGeometry="{StaticResource path}"
                    Duration="0:0:2">
            </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Height="20" Width="20">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform x:Name="transform"/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource sb}">
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You have to take a closer look at the documentation of the PointAnimationUsingPath class. It needs a PathGeometry, not a Path, and it would target a property of type Point. A better approach for moving an element along a path would be the animation of the Matrix property of a MatrixTransform in the element's RenderTransform property by a MatrixAnimationUsingPath. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17843284/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Thank you. Using a matrix transform was my first attempt. How would I do that in a storyboard in the case where I need to define the path geometry in the object XAMl, then pass that geometry to the storyboard that exists inside a style? Also, if possible I would love for the path to be a circle.

Comment: Bind the PathGeometry property, or assign a StaticResource. For a circle, declare two arc segments in the PathGeometry.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have no clue how to do this, but XAML seems a bit picky about what can and can't be passed from one structure to another. My end goal is to have  style with a storyboard that includes an animation. I'd like to apply this style to a button such that when it first becomes visible, it follows the animation path. I edited the code to reflect the updates.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect changes.

Comment: I get an error complaining that the storyboard is not freezable.

Comment: OK, so I tried something else(see code above). I took @Clemens advice to use a MatrixTransform. I made the StoryBoard a resource so that I could reuse it in another button. I call the StoryBoard in the code behind...(C#)Storyboard sb = grid1.Resources["sb"] as Storyboard;'' This doe not do anything when I trigger it. Not sure what I am doing wrong this time.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works...

```
<Window x:Class="EllipseFollowsPath.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EllipseFollowsPath"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="768" Width="1366">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="path">
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="921,384" IsClosed="False">
                    <ArcSegment Point="445,384" Size="60 60" 
                    SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"/>
                </PathFigure>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="445,384" IsClosed="False">
                    <ArcSegment Point="921,384" Size="60 60" 
                    SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
        <Storyboard x:Key="sb" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <MatrixAnimationUsingPath
                    Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix"
                    PathGeometry="{StaticResource path}"
                    Duration="0:0:2">
            </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Height="20" Width="20">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform x:Name="transform"/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource sb}">
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```